# Generate unique tags to repeating results of a command

Tags: bash, shell, tags

I have a script running which generates continuous output such as:

```
/AtherosC_92:f1:a7  BTHub4-NJ8S -82
/AtherosC_92:f1:a7  BTHub4-NJ8S -81
/95:8c:ed:6d:65:f5  Home245 -84
/AtherosC_92:f1:a7  BTHub4-NJ8S -78
/3d:cc:54:d1:4f:f6  BTWifi2 -82
/Apple_e5:e8:2d SKYBD80F    -71
/Apple_e5:e8:2d SKYBD80F    -71
/Apple_e5:e8:2d SKYBD80F    -72
```

Each line is comprised of 3 sections (string, string, int as above).  I need to assign each line a unique identifier based on the first string of each line, creating an output like this:

```
/1 AtherosC_92:f1:a7    BTHub4-NJ8S -82
/1 AtherosC_92:f1:a7    BTHub4-NJ8S -81
/2 95:8c:ed:6d:65:f5    Home245 -84
/1 AtherosC_92:f1:a7    BTHub4-NJ8S -78
/3 3d:cc:54:d1:4f:f6    BTWifi2 -82
/4 Apple_e5:e8:2d   SKYBD80F    -71
/4 Apple_e5:e8:2d   SKYBD80F    -71
/4 Apple_e5:e8:2d   SKYBD80F    -72
```

Any suggestions as to how his could be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pure Bash solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A seen
tag=0
while read; do
    read -r first _ <<< "$REPLY"
    [[ $first ]] || continue
    if [[ -z ${seen["$first"]} ]]; then
        seen["$first"]=$((++tag))
    fi
    printf '\\%d %s\n' "${seen["$first"]}" "$REPLY"
done
```

---

The following is based on @rici's solution (thanks!):

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A seen=()
while read && read -r first _ <<< "$REPLY" ; do
    [[ $first ]] && printf '\\%d %s\n' "${seen["$first"]=$((${#seen[@]}+1))}" "$REPLY"
done
```

Comment: `declare -Ai seen` ... (without the `if`): `: ${seen["$first"]=${#seen[@]}+1}`

Comment: Thanks very much for your input folks, I'd definitely favour a bash solution if possible...I've tried running this (called 'number.sh'), but it's throwing up these errors when I try to pipe the output from the first command into it: 
./number.sh: line 3: declare: -A: invalid option
./number.sh: line 5: Azurewav_f8:89:6d: syntax error in expression (error token is ":89:6d")
I can't find -A on the declare documentation either, what am I missing here?

Comment: @youcloudsofdoom bad luck, it seems you're running an old version of Bash (Bash 3). Are you on OSX? This solution uses associative arrays that appeared in Bash 4. So either upgrade to Bash 4 or use another solution. I'm sorry about this.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf ah I was running it on osx to test it, that's the issue.  It's actually being deployed on a raspi though, which I just tested and it worked great!  Thank you.  One more question though - can you think of a good way to be able to reuse numbers that have not been seen in a while?  It'd be very useful to reuse an earlier number if a matching output to it hasn't been seen in say 30 seconds, rather than generate a new number.

Comment: @youcloudsofdoom Of course it's doable but not without a lot of modifications: we'll need a second array to store a timestamp (when the number is last seen) and then scan this array to see if we can reuse an old number (if seen more than 30 seconds ago). It's not difficult but not completely trivial either. Do you really need that?

Comment: Yeah, it's become apparent that it's a needed element.  I'll open a new question for it though, but I'd like to acknowledge again your help here in putting this together, it's massively appreciated.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf have tried this in a new question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29118889/check-and-reuse-old-numbers-from-a-numbered-list), but had no response.  Any suggestion as to how to better phrase what I need?

Answer (score 0):

Or in Perl:

```
my $i = 1;
my %d;
while (<>) {
  chomp;
  my ($id, @r) = split;
  $id =~ s#^/##;
  unless (exists $d{$id}) {
    $d{$id} = $i++;
  }
  print "/$d{$id} $id @r\n";
}
```