# check and reuse old numbers from a numbered list

Tags: bash, list, timestamp

I have a script running in Debian on a RPi which generates over time numbered outputs like so, with the first string of each line being used to group matching items together:

```
/1 AtherosC_92:f1:a7    BTHub4-NJ8S -82
/1 AtherosC_92:f1:a7    BTHub4-NJ8S -81
/2 95:8c:ed:6d:65:f5    Home245 -84
/1 AtherosC_92:f1:a7    BTHub4-NJ8S -78
/3 3d:cc:54:d1:4f:f6    BTWifi2 -82
/4 Apple_e5:e8:2d   SKYBD80F    -71
/4 Apple_e5:e8:2d   SKYBD80F    -71
/4 Apple_e5:e8:2d   SKYBD80F    -72
```

With the grouping done with the following script:

```
declare -Ai seen=()
while read && read -r first _ <<< "$REPLY" ; do
    [[ $first ]] && printf '/%d %s\n' "${seen["$first"]=$((${#seen[@]}+1))}" "$REPLY"
done
```

The number at the start of each list is being used to sort them in the destination program.  I need a method to check before generating a higher number to see if a lower number has come up recently (in the last 30 seconds or so) and reuse that number if it has not.  So for example, if /1 had not been output by the primary command in >30 sec, the following would occur when a third unique string is generated:

```
/1 AtherosC_92:f1:a7    BTHub4-NJ8S -82
/1 AtherosC_92:f1:a7    BTHub4-NJ8S -81
/2 95:8c:ed:6d:65:f5    Home245 -84
/1 3d:cc:54:d1:4f:f6    BTWifi2 -82
```

Are there any suggestions as to how this could be achieved?  Either in bash or anything else?

Comment: Is it important that you do this in Bash as opposed to a real programming language?  (To be clear, I use Bash all the time, but not for data analysis.)

Comment: When you renumbered the fourth line, how do you know a following line with 3d:cc... should be renumbered as well? Does it meet your requirements when the output is firsted stored in tmp files 1, 2, .. and renumber the output afterwards based on the last mutation date/time of the tmp files?

Comment: My requirements are that it needs to be a process running alongside the constant output of the primary command, so saving to a file and doing the analysis afterwards won't suit, unfortunately.  Possibly some sort of timestamp attached to an array which stores recently used numbers  and checks against when they were last seen before issuing a new, higher number?

Answer (score 1):

This is a follow-up of [Generate unique tags to repeating results of a command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29049326/generate-unique-tags-to-repeating-results-of-a-command/29049572?noredirect=1#comment46791504_29049572)

Here's a possibility: we'll introduce two more arrays, `tags` and `tags_time`. Their keys are the tags used; the fields of `tags` are the corresponding string in your output (the keys of the associative array `seen`), and the fields of `tags_time` are the timestamps when the tag was last used.

We then introduce a function `get_tag` the parses the integers from `1` up, and if an integer is free (i.e., corresponds to no keys or has been used more that `delay` seconds ago), delete it from our data and return it as the new index to use.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A seen
tags=()
tags_time=()

delay=30

get_tag() {
   local i
   for ((i=1;;++i)); do
      if [[ -z ${tags[i]} ]] || ((tags_time[i] < SECONDS-delay)); then
         break
      fi
   done
   if [[ ${tags[i]} ]]; then
      unset 'seen[${tags[$i]}]' "tags[i]" "tags_time[i]"
   fi
   get_tag_ret=$i
}

while read; do
   read -r first _ <<< "$REPLY"
   [[ $first ]] || continue
   if [[ -z ${seen["$first"]} ]]; then
      get_tag
      seen["$first"]=$get_tag_ret
      tags[get_tag_ret]=$first
      tags_time[get_tag_ret]=$SECONDS
   fi
   printf '\\%d %s\n' "${seen["$first"]}" "$REPLY"
done
```

I haven't tested it.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much for your help @gniourf_gniourf, and in the patient explanation - I've just been running some tests with this and it appears to work great!  I'll let you know if anything comes up in further testing of it.  Again, many thanks.